# Integrating Blueimp (Jquery uploader) in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, blueimp

I have been running here and there for quite some time now and still have not figured out how to include [Blue imp jquery plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in codeigniter, i have followed the instructions which are provided in this URL [Integrate Blueimp with codeigniter](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Jquery-file-upload-8.8.5,with-codeigniter-2.1.x) and i can browse and all the jquery functions works fine but when i click on start upload i am getting an internal server error (error attached to this post).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i am really stuck and not able to do anything, Please help !!!!

Comment: Oh good I have cracked that error, it was csrf_protection feature of code-igniter, it always has problems when a form is submitted through post method, anyway now that problem is out of the question, but a new one has occurred :(, but I guess i can figured it out but in case if any one already knew the answer please help, the problem is that i am getting a unexpected token while trying to upload the files :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh good I have cracked that error, it was csrf_protection feature of code-igniter, it always has problems when a form is submitted through post method, Both the problem has been solved thank you stackOverflow :)